# WPF c# datepicker yyyy/mm/dd without hh/mm/ss?

Tags: wpf, date

I'am saving date in database from Date Picker.

```
uj["datum"] = dpDatum.SelectedDate;
```

[http://i59.tinypic.com/211ujk3.png][1]

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select h.neve, f.neve,datum, tol,ig from foglalas f,helyszin h where f.helyszin_id=h.ID and f.helyszin_id=" +
                 (cbSzur.SelectedIndex + 1) + " and f.datum> @search ", c1);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", dpSzur.SelectedDate);
```

and when i want to get back the date i get this format  `dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss AM`
BUT i want only this format `dd/mm/yy`

How can i resolve this probleme?

add to data grid

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select h.neve as Helyiség, f.neve as Fellépő,datum, tol,ig from foglalas f,helyszin h where f.helyszin_id=h.ID and f.helyszin_id=" +
                 (cbSzur.SelectedIndex + 1) + " and f.datum> @search ", c1);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", ((DateTime)dpSzur.SelectedDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "lista");
                dLista.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["lista"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: How are you adding the data to the datagrid?

Comment: Yes i have added to question in top

Comment: Here is an article that talks more about datagrid, data and formatting.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings

Comment: its okay, but unfortunately there isnt any DATE formatting

Comment: Where, in that article?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make, is you need to understand how Xaml, templates etc, work in WPF. That will help your grid code.  Do you

Comment: Can you add your XAML to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to change your sql query to return the date in format you want :

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select h.neve as Helyiség, f.neve as Fellépő,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),datum,110), tol,ig from foglalas f,helyszin h where f.helyszin_id=h.ID and f.helyszin_id=" +
             (cbSzur.SelectedIndex + 1) + " and f.datum> @search ", c1);
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) link for list of formats

Answer (score 0):

you can format it yourself~

```
((DateTime)dpSzur.SelectedDate).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: @user3793233 cast the object to DateTime first I guess

Comment: ERROR :"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

I have changed DD/MM/YY to DD/MM/YYYY and now run the code, but the same problem, i got DD/MM/YYYY HH/MM/SS AM

Comment: OK, I think I got your question abit better now, you mean you want to format it when you are DISPLAYING on the date picker?

Comment: YES , when i wana display in datagrid